# How exactly can I check to see if a remote branch exists?

Tags: git, github

I am reviewing a pull request from a user on a library that my company is sponsoring. The branch that the said project is of course `company:master`. The branch where the pull request is coming from is `user:fix-shell`. Now I've pulled the code and ran a `git branch` and I don't see the branch existing. I tried a `git fetch --all` which returned nothing. Then I tried `git fetch user:fix-shell` and returned this error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname user: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I then tried `git ls-remote` and did not see anything that was `user:fix-shell`.

Can I rightly conclude that this pull request does not exist anymore to check out? Is there a command that I haven't tried yet that I should?

Comment: Try `git branch -a` to also list *remote* branches

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I ran the command and found nothing pointing to `user:fix-shell`. Would I conclude that it doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: If the branch does not appear under `git branch -a` it can be safely be considered non existent. My last check would be try to change branch by calling the command `git checkout branch_name`, if it swaps the branch it means there was a remote copy, if it returns `error: pathspec 'branch_name' did not match any file(s) known to git.` then it means no such branch exists anymore.